why when I run the system Crystal Report Login Failed?
I have old system using C# and crystal reports ,
In my computer for developer the system and reports running and working without any issue my computer O/S windows 10
but I have new computer using windows 11 when I publish the system and install it on the new computer
the system running but I cannot run any report and always show message
Database Login failed !
this is the code :
 private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RPT.barcode myreport = new RPT.barcode();    // report path folder and report 
            myreport.SetParameterValue("@ORDER_ID", txtOrder.Text);
            myreport.SetDatabaseLogon("db_user", "password", "server", "db_name");
            RPT.RPT_TESTS myform = new RPT.RPT_TESTS();
            myform.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myreport;
            myform.ShowDialog();
        }

from 2 days I am trying and trying but I cannot find the reason and still got same error I saw also posts on the site and changed the code but same error !
Please I need your help what is the mistake and how to solve this issue ?
